# rejected error in git when trying to pull remote repo

Tags: git

1. I created my repo (A) and added all files on initial commit.
2. Then I extracted a couple files across that repo (A) and checked them in another git repo (B) that is not connected to (A).
3. repo (B) is converted to a github repo
4. then from repo (A) I did git remote add githubrepo git@github....
5. then from repo (A) I did git branch newbranch
6. then from repo (A) I did git checkout newbranch
7. then from repo (A) I did git pull githubrepo master:newbranch

and I get

```
rom github.com:user2323/githubrepo 
! [rejected]        master     -> master:newbranch  (non-fast-forward)
```

Comment: You can't just copy files from A to B and expect to be able to pull from B to A. That is absolutely not how Git works. The histories of the two projects are completely different. You cannot do what you are trying to do. You should make a bare **clone** of A and push the cloned repo to github.

Comment: My situation is that I don't want to expose the entire repo to everyone in the team, I want only a couple of the files accessible in a different repo and maintain some kind of sync and the git submodules doesn't work for me as the files are not all in the same directory.

Comment: You can't do this, this isn't how Git works. You'll need to manually copy the files out of one repo and into the other.

Answer (score 1):

Git is suggesting that the pull would result in a non-fast-forward update, in other words that the `master` branch histories between repos A and B are divergent. That sounds totally plausible, given step 2. You'll probably want to track that branch locally, rather than relying on `git pull`:

`git checkout --track -b newbranch githubrepo/master`